# 4 rowSums* 2 colSums to get 8 cell values

Tags: r

This is probably simple but somehow I'm missing it.  If I create a matrix as follows:

`m <- matrix(c(154,180,104,438,132,126,131,389),ncol=2)`

I then multiply as

`e <- rowSums(m)*colSums(m)`

The resulting `e` is just each value from the 1st sums vector times the 2nd sums vector (while recycling the 2nd) to produce:

`[1] 250536 238068 205860 643406`

What I actually want is to get is a matrix of 8 values where each cell value is rowSums(i)*colSums(k) where i = 1 to 4 and k = 1 to 2

Comment: Are you looking for the `outer` function, i.e. : `outer(rowSums(m), colSums(m))`?

Comment: Yes - thank you!  If you like to add it as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the product of every element in `x` with every element in `y` by using the `outer` function.

```r
m <- matrix(c(154,180,104,438,132,126,131,389),ncol=2)
x <- rowSums(m)
y <- colSums(m)

outer(x, y)
#>        [,1]   [,2]
#> [1,] 250536 222508
#> [2,] 268056 238068
#> [3,] 205860 182830
#> [4,] 724452 643406
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you are familiar with linear algebra notation, the following does the same:

```r
x %*% t(y)
#>        [,1]   [,2]
#> [1,] 250536 222508
#> [2,] 268056 238068
#> [3,] 205860 182830
#> [4,] 724452 643406
```

The outer function can also be used for other operations than multiplication:

```r
outer(x, y, "+")
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,] 1162 1064
#> [2,] 1182 1084
#> [3,] 1111 1013
#> [4,] 1703 1605
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that R recycles vectors when they're different lengths. You can get the answer you want by using the matrix multiplication operator %*%.

```
e <- rowSums(m) %*% t(colSums(m))
```